# Symfony3 : send data to Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts, symfony

I want to display some charts with Highcharts in my Symfony3 app.

To do this, I have to get some data from my DB and send it to Highcharts. Here comes the problem : I don't know how to do this. I created an array with all the data needed but I can't use it just by setting up a twig variable.

How can I send these datas ? 
Here's my code :

Controller

```
$repartitionArray = [];
            $statsArray = [];
            for ($i = 0 ; $i < count($statscolle) ; $i++) {
                $groupe[$i] = $statscolle[$i]->getGroupes()->getName();
                $repartitionsColles[$i] = $em->getRepository(RepartitionColle::class)->findBy(['idStatColle' => $statscolle], ['note' => 'ASC']);

                for ($j = 0; $j < count($repartitionsColles[$i]); $j++){
                    $note[$j] = $repartitionsColles[$i]->getNote();
                    $nombre[$j] = $repartitionsColles[$i]->getNombre();
                    $repartitionArray[$i] = [$note[$j], $nombre[$j]];
                }

                $statsArray[] = ["name" => $groupe[$i], "data" => $repartitionArray[$i]];
            }

            $series = $statsArray;

            return $this->render("PACESStatistiqueBundle:Default:collapsideColle.html.twig", ["titre" => $colle->getNom(),
            "data" => $series]);
```

Twig :

```
<div class="center">
        <div id="repNotesColles" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
</div>



{% block javascripts %}
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var repartitionNotesOfColle = Highcharts.chart('repNotesColles', {
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: {{ titre }}
        },
        xAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Notes'
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: 'Effectif'
            }
        },
        series: 
    });
})

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Why don't you use Symfony bundle for that ? https://github.com/marcaube/ObHighchartsBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/usage.md seems very straightforward

Comment: I wanted to but I saw that it hasn't been updated since July and it doesn't use the last version of Highcharts.

Comment: I tried the bundle and it fullfill my needs. Thank you !